# Palindrome Function Issue

Tags: python

I was writing a function to see whether a string is a palindrome or not and came across an issue with my code. It seems to provide the right answer to most strings, but not to all!
Here it is:

```
def isPalindrome(string):
    for letter in string:
        if letter == string[(len(string)-1-string.index(letter))]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

What is wrong with it? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "It seems to provide the right answer to most strings, but not to all!"—can you provide examples? Please read [ask].

Comment: Do you know what `return` does? How many letters does your function look at before it `return`s?

Answer (score 1):

### Use string slicing

- `string[start:stop:step]`

  - `string[::-1]`

    - Starts from the end and moves towards the beginning, one step at a time.
    - In other words, slice the word, beginning at last index and move towards the first index.
  - See [String Slicing](https://realpython.com/python-strings/#string-slicing)
- This is the most [pythonic](https://realpython.com/learning-paths/writing-pythonic-code/) way to solve the problem.

```py
def palindrome(word: str) -> bool:
    return word == word[::-1]

palindrom('scarf')
>>> False  # because scarf != fracs

palindrome('rotator')
>>> True  # because rotator == rotator
```

### Regarding your current implementation

- Your function stops after the first letter because the `return` statement immediately stops the function and returns the value.
- There are many ways to fix your code

  - Change `return` to `yield`, which will return a [generator](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/).
  - Iterating the generator, with [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list), will then show `True` or `False` for each letter
  - The result is a palindrome if [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) the items are True
- This is not an efficient way to solve this problem.

```py
def isPalindrome(string):
    for letter in string:
        if letter == string[(len(string)-1-string.index(letter))]:
            yield True
        else:
            yield False

test = list(isPalindrome('rotator'))
print(test)
>>> [True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
print(all(test) == True)
>>> True

test = list(isPalindrome('scarf'))
print(test)
>>> [False, False, True, False, False]
print(all(test) == True)
>>> False
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're returning true in cases where not the whole word matches. Only return `False` if any of the letters dont match, and return `True` at the end of the loop.

```
def isPalindrome(string):
    for letter in string:
        if not letter == string[(len(string)-1-string.index(letter))]:
             return False
    return True
```